# XLST transform from XML to HTML results "HTML 1.0 version not supported" error

Tags: java, html, xslt, saxon, jcabi

I'm trying to convert XML to HTMl using Java Saxon library with Jcabi-XML.

XSLT:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" version="5.0"/>

  <xsl:template match="/content">
    <html lang="en">
      <head></head>
      <body></body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<content>This text results error</content>
```

Java:

```java
package com.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import com.jcabi.xml.XMLDocument;
import com.jcabi.xml.XSLDocument;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        try {
            final XMLDocument xml = new XMLDocument(
                new File("test.xml")
            );
            final XSLDocument xlst = new XSLDocument(
                new File("test.xslt")
            );
            xlst.transform(xml);
        } catch (final FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This code results `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Unsupported HTML version: 1.0`.

I explicitly set HTML5 version, but it doesn't affect to result. How to avoid this error?

Libraries versions:

- Jcabi-XML: `0.23.2`
- Saxon-HE: `9.8.0-15`

Comment: Which Saxon version is that exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the stack trace (showing

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Unsupported HTML version: 1.0
    at com.jcabi.xml.XMLDocument.asString(XMLDocument.java
```

the exception is triggered by the line https://github.com/jcabi/jcabi-xml/blob/0.23.2/src/main/java/com/jcabi/xml/XMLDocument.java#L505 doing `trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.VERSION, "1.0");`, that seems to be the culprit.

So basically it seems that the library uses Saxon with the JAXP Transformer API but at that line tries to override the `version` as `1.0` and Saxon indeed doesn't support it for the HTML output it is trying to do based on the `html` output method being set in the stylesheet.

As you want to use Saxon 9.8 (or perhaps later, given that the supported versions are 10 and 11), I would suggest to look at Saxon's API documented at https://www.saxonica.com/documentation11/index.html#!using-xsl/embedding/s9api-transformation and just use that API to perform the XSLT transformation.

```
   Processor processor = new Processor(false);
   XsltCompiler compiler = processor.newXsltCompiler();
   XsltExecutable stylesheet = compiler.compile(new StreamSource(new File("test.xslt")));
   Serializer out = processor.newSerializer(new File("result.html"));
   Xslt30Transformer transformer = stylesheet.load30();
   transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new File("test.xml")), out);
```

Comment: Thanks for investigating source code. I don't have any experience in Java to spot this issue, thank you for showing this error reason

Answer (score 1):

Adding `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` into `xsl:stylesheet` tag fixes this error:

Full XSLT file after change:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" version="5.0"/>

  <xsl:template match="/content">
    <html lang="en">
      <head></head>
      <body></body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Actually, what fixes the error is changing the HTML version from 1.0 to 5.0. The code in your question does NOT produce the claimed error.

Comment: @michael.hor257k now I have working XSLT which is extended XSLT from answer. If I remove line, that I suggest in answer, error from question will shows. Please, specify where exactly I change HTML version. Because difference of this codes is only `xmlns=...` line, I can't see where HTML version changes

Comment: As you can see here, the code in your question does not produce the error you claim: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbspVbF. The error message you quote states clearly that the problem is HTML version 1.0. You do not have HTML version 1.0 in your code (at least not in the code you posted here).

Comment: @MaxSmirnov, which Saxon version exactly do you use?

Comment: @MartinHonnen `9.8.0-15` of `Saxon-HE`

Comment: @MaxSmirnov, I have tried to reproduce the problem running Saxon HE 9.8.0.15 Java from the command line, using your stylesheet from the question and an XML input sample having e.g. `<content>Test</content>`. However, I don't get any error. Do you run Saxon from the command line when you get the error? If not, can you try? Also, if you are running code with Java that performs the transformation, perhaps edit your question showing that code as well to try to allow others to reproduce the problem. Also make sure it is the code you have shown that triggers the message.

Comment: @MartinHonnen added java code, jcabi-xml mention (that uses saxon under the hood), and xml document. Following code reproduces error.

Comment: @MaxSmirnov, I will have a look at the Java code, but given that it uses various libraries outside of Saxon, can you also check whether your XSLT and XML gives that error if you run Saxon 9.8.0.15 from the command line? Also, as for that library `jcabi.xml`, are you familiar with its codebase? It seems to be using DOM anywhere, does it ensure that each DOM is namespace aware?

Comment: @MartinHonnen with codebase - no. I try to use Java for XSLT manipulations and find this library the only good one. I